# How to see the last few keystrokes in vim?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I hit the wrong keys on my laptop's small keyboard, and odd navigation or editing occurs (sometimes a feature that's new to me).

Although I can undo the editing (`u`) or navigation (`control-o`), I don't know what I did wrong, so it's difficult to avoid it in future. It's also frustrating to not know what just happened. So, I would like to be able to see my last few keystrokes.

A bit like `:set showcmd`, but to show the literal keystrokes, and (ideally) a short history of them.

I've only found commandline and navigation history in help/google.

---

To clarify: I'm not looking for commandline history, but *keystroke history*. e.g. did I press `)` accidentally and go to the next sentence? Did I press `dd` and delete a line?  I guess it's similar to a *keystroke logger*.

Commandline history (`:history`) only shows commands entered at the `:` prompt.

Answer (score 6):

A bit old, but I've just found this on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1nbxm0/are_there_plugins_for_tracking_frequent/):

You can start vim with the -w flag to write all keystrokes in a file. See `:h -w`

```
vim -w filename
```

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, the closest you can get is the <kbd>q</kbd> command, which records your keystrokes into a register of your choice.  Obviously, that has to be set up a priori as it's intended for complex repeats, although you could probably hack something to start recording on every file open.  There's the matter of memory usage and that annoying "recording" prompt though.

Probably the most straightforward way would be to install keylogging software.  I don't have any personal experience with these, but the security implications are probably mild if you get it from a trustworthy source or build it yourself, set it to only log to memory not a disk, only have a buffer the size of a sentence or so, or only log for vim windows.

Comment: good idea!  You can inspect the macro stored with `q` using `:reg`. For example, if you begin `qx` then type `kkjjdd/hello^M:w^M` (and `q` to end), then `:reg x` will print that out (the `^M` is carriage return; everything is recorded, including `/` searches and `:` commands).

Comment: I'm been using `q`, and it works well; but output with `:reg` doesn't wrap, so the most recent keystrokes are often lost off the right side of the screen (it's common to be long, because it records everything - e.g. if you enter a few lines of text, all those keystrokes are included). But, it did tell me I sometimes  hit `n` instead of `b`, casting me off into the file instead of back a word.  I'm still hoping vim can do exactly what I want; I'll leave it one more day.

Comment: @13ren, you can also paste the value of a register into the text window with `"[reg letter]p`.

Answer (score 2):

More recently I came across a logging plugin for Vim and it reminded me of this question:

http://wolever.net/~wolever/wiki/vim-logging

It basically records everything you do for later analysis, it was intended for getting statistics about command usage but should work perfectly for finding what those magic commands you accidentally entered were.

Answer (score 1):

`:history` will show your command history - that should help you uncover the new features that we all uncover in vim with misplaced keystrokes.

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned in the question that I already found commandline history - what I'm looking for is keystroke history. To clarify, did I press `)` accidentally and go to the next sentence? Did I press `dd` and delete a line?  The commandline history doesn't show these; it only shows commands entered at the `:` prompt.

Answer (score 1):

[Gundo](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304) - Is probably worth a look, whilst perhaps not exactly what you are looking it will help slightly.

It lets you visualise the Vim undo tree, this means you will be able to see the last edits that happened. For example if you accidentally deleted a line or some such this will show up in the tree, however, it doesn't show you the actual keystrokes that were pushed and will not show things such as cursor movements.

Comment: Thanks. Gundo is an amazing project, based on vim's amazing (but unusable) undo trees - I'm not aware of any tool of any kind that has it (except for git and other version control systems, which are based on the very concept, at a larger scale). But, as you note, this doesn't answer my question because it doesn't show keystroke. For reverting errant edits, regular undo works fine - there's no need to use a more complex solution when a simpler one already solves it perfectly. However, I think you were just using this as an excuse to promote Gundo... and I can't really fault you on that. :-)